# Android, issue in posting message on my wall on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, sharing

I'm using Facebook SDK and I want to post message on my wall. It's near two days that I plow the Internet but i was not successful to find my problem. Let me say what I did.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "Try to create activity...");

        // Close activity if app id is not specified.
        if (FACEBOOK_APPID == null  ||  FACEBOOK_APPID == "") {
            Log.e(TAG, "Facebook Applicaton ID must be specified before running this screen.");
            closeActivity();
        }

        // Getting extra info which is passed by caller activity.
        // If we are here by mistake(Caller didn't send required parameter) close activity.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No data passed to this activity. Activity closed.");
            closeActivity();
        }
        // Get Message
        message = extras.getString("FB_WALLPOST");
//        Log.i(TAG, "message>>> " + message);


        mFacebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APPID);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

        SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
        SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());

//        mFacebook.dialog(FacebookActivity.this, "feed", params, new SampleDialogListener());

        Thread thread = new BasicThread();
        thread.start();

    }
```

Based on my research I found that `Facebook.dialog` cannot be used. That's why Its commented out.
Also I found that we need to use `Facebook.request` instead of that. I found `Note that this method blocks waiting for a network response, so do not call it in a UI thread.` in its implementation in SDK. Therefore, I created another thread to handle posting process.

When thread starts following method will be invoked.

```
public class BasicThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try{
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
            parameters.putString("name", "Name");
            parameters.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
            parameters.putString("caption", "Caption");
            parameters.putString("description", "Description");

            String  response = mFacebook.request("me/feed",parameters,"POST");
            Log.v("response", response);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Those people who suggested this code had been told that the method works fine for them. However, I have no idea why it doesn't work for me.

response in logcat:

```
09-16 17:06:21.860: D/Facebook-Util(26652): POST URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
09-16 17:06:23.350: V/response(26652): {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No access token is being sent, though, is it?
Try something like:

```
String token = getAccessToken();

if (token){
    parameters.putString("access_token", token);
    String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed",parameters,"POST");
} else {
    // Log the user in
}
```